# How can I target an element that's nested in the sibling tag of another element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Example code:

```
<input type="radio" id="option_1" name="radio_group" checked="checked" value="1">

<label for="option_1"><span class="categories_on_main_overlay">OPTION 1</span></label>
```

How can I target, in jQuery, the text of the span ('OPTION 1') within the label that's a sibling of the input tag.

So far, I've tried the following which I thought would work, but I get nothing:

```
$("input[name='radio_group']:checked").next('label').next('span').text();
```

Comment: The `<span>` element is a child of `<label>`. Why then [`.next('span')`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)? -> [Traversing | jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close but you don't want the second `.next()`, that looks for a sibling and you want the child. So use `.find()` instead:

```
$("input[name='radio_group']:checked").next('label').find('span').text();
```

```js
console.log($("input[name='radio_group']:checked").next('label').find('span').text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="option_1" name="radio_group" checked="checked" value="1">

<label for="option_1"><span class="categories_on_main_overlay">OPTION 1</span></label>
```

Comment: Thanks: that works. I always wondered why .child wasn't an option, but .find (finding within) makes plenty of sense.

Comment: @Chain There's no `.child()` method but there is a [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) one. The difference? As the docs state, "The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well. "